# The difference of eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ Matrix and $v$ an eigenvector to the
> eigenvalue $a$ and $w$ an eigenvector to the eigenvalue $b$, $v \neq w$.
> Show that $v-w$ is an eigenvector of $A$ if and only if $a=b$.

I am trying to prove the statement above.

$\Leftarrow$ seems obvious: $A(v-w)=Av-Aw=av-bw=a(v-w)$

Can someone help me with the other direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $\lambda$ is the corresponding eigenvalue of $v-w$. Then,
$$
av - bw = A(v-w) = \lambda (v-w)
$$
This implies $(a-\lambda)v + (\lambda-b)w =0$. Since eigenvectors corresponding to distinct eigenvalues are linearly independent, we conclude $a=\lambda=b$.

Comment: I am confused by your answer. $v$ corresponds to $a$ and $w$ corresponds to $b$. We are trying to show that $a = b$, but a crucial step in your proof uses that $a \neq b$? Am I misunderstanding?

Comment: @terran No you are understanding it correctly. Suppose $a\neq b$. These are distinct eigenvalues, so you can derive $a=b$, which contradicts our supposition. It is a proof by contradiction.

Comment: Okay I see, thank you. I will leave my answer up as a different way to prove the result, although I think your method is more elegant.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $v - w$ is an eigenvector of $A$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $c$. Since the collection $ \{ v, w, v - w \}$ is linearly dependent, it must be the case that the eigenvalues $a, b$, and $c$ are not distinct, i.e. at least two are equal. In fact, each of the cases $a = b, a = c$, and $b = c$ implies that $a = b = c$. For example, if $a = c$ then
$$
av - aw = a(v - w) = c(v - w) = A(v - w) = Av - Aw = av - bw \implies aw = bw,
$$
which implies that $a = b$ since $w$ is not zero.